# Mysql - Table design for authorization checking

Tags: mysql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table called **Student** and it is used to save the relationship between Class and Student

| Class | Student (PK) |
| --- | --- |
| Class 1 | Peter |
| Class 1 | Harry |
| Class 2 | Sally |
| Class 2 | Tommy |

And there is another table called **Teacher**

| Teacher(PK) |
| --- |
| John |
| Emma |
| Chris |

Finally, a many to many table is used for authorization and describe the responsibility of each teacher. For example, John can access the profile and Academic performance of every student of Class 1

| Teacher (PK) | Class(PK) |
| --- | --- |
| John | Class 1 |
| Chris | Class 2 |
| Emma | Class 2 |

The basic structure is work properly. However, Chris, who should be teacher of class 2 but he needs to access the profile of Peter from Class A because of special reason. Therefore, I try to update the table structure.

| Teacher(PK) | Class(PK) | Student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Class 1 | Null |
| Chris | Class 1 | Peter |
| Chris | Class 2 | Null |
| Emma | Class 2 | Null |

Error is thrown because the key "Chris-Class1" is duplicated but I can't set student as part of primary key because nullable is not allow. There are a few methods that can be solved:

1. Add an auto increment field can remove the primary key setting of teacher and class

| Index(PK) | Teacher | Class | Student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Class 1 | Null |
| 2 | Chris | Class 1 | Peter |
| 3 | Chris | Class 2 | Null |
| 4 | Emma | Class 2 | Null |

2. Or separate it to two tables

| Teacher (PK) | Class(PK) |
| --- | --- |
| John | Class 1 |
| Chris | Class 2 |
| Emma | Class 2 |

| Teacher(PK) | Class(PK) | Student(PK) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | Class 1 | Peter |

I would like to ask which approach should be better to handle this case?

Comment: normalize the joe structure caLSS8WITH ID; NAME) sudent table teacher tables and brdge table for all

Answer (score 0):

> he needs to access the profile of Peter from Class A

Use two `JOINs` rather than adding an extra table.

(Maybe I can be clearer if you provide that 'profile' and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.)